# Change Cell Accessory Type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a tableview called `allone.h` with cells that are all subtitle style cells with a disclosure indicator.
The  subtitle text is generated dynamically, so it's pretty likely each cell will have different subtitle text.

I have an if statement that says **if the text = "hello, world"**, then change accessory type to `detailDisclosureIndicator`. When the `detailDisclosureIndicator` is pressed, it pushes a new controller, changes the subtitle text, then pops that view controller and returns to `allone.h`. The problem is, it still shows the `detailDisclosureIndicator` even **if the text != "hello, world"**. I tried changing the style in `viewWillAppear`, but I don't have access to cell.

Here is my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//populate cells with stuff

    if([cell.detailTextLabel.text isEqualToString:@"hello, world"]){
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
}
```

So I guess my question is, how do I change the accessory type *back* once I return to `allone.h` and the cell's text is no longer "hello, world"?

Comment: Have you tried reloading the UITableView? You don't need to reload all the UITableView, just the cell you want to change it.

Comment: @rocir: I'm not sure what you mean by just the cell you want to change, but ever time viewWillAppear for "allone.h", the tableview gets reloaded. Still displays the detaildisclosureindicator on the cell that once originally had the text "hello, world". I'm just unsure which method to put the new accessory type in.

Comment: You can do that in your -[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]. Just like an "else" for your if statement. And to reload the cell, you can just call reloadData or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:. Are you making sure you change the detailTextLabel before you check that in the if statement?

Comment: You must have an array that you are using to fill the subtitle. You need to replace the text at that position inside the array as well. So when next time the Tableview reloads, it fetches the changed text.

Comment: @rocir: It was as simple as adding an else statement. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in your -[UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]. Just like an "else" for your if statement.

And to reload the cell, you can just call reloadData or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:.

Answer (score 0):

I think cell.detailTextLable is equal to nil. So cell accessory doesn't change. Please double check it. did you configure the cell before?